# Accumulate values in C#

Tags: c#, accumulate

I'm trying to replicate a simple action of accumulating a value a n-th amount of times. So something like value 4 take 10 times would be: [0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36]. What am I doing wrong?

```
        public static IList SumValues(int value, int times)
        {
            List<object> sums = new List<object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < times; i = i + 1)
            {
                while (i < times)
                    sums.Add(value);
            }
            return sums;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you are creating a list of `object` when its very clearly `int` 's in the list.  I have changed the code to return an `IEnumerable<int>` so you can iterate without materializing.  With that in mind you can make your code a bit shorter:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> SumValues(int initialValue, int iterations)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        yield return initialValue * i;
    }       
}
```

If you need it in a `List<T>` or an `Array` you can just call the appropriate method (`.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`):

```
List<int> someIntList = SumValues(4, 10).ToList();
int[] someIntArray = SumValues(4, 10).ToArray();
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u7whTK)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! I'm a newbie to C# and programming in general so all of what you explained is very very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static IList SumValues(int value, int times)
{
   List<int> sums = new List<int>();
   for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
   {
       sums.Add(i*value);
   }
   return sums;
}
```

Comment: @ljumbor this wouldn't work either, I think you mean sums.Add(value*i).

Comment: Of course. I'm too tired, should go to bed :)
Corrected my answer.

Comment: @ljumbor it wouldn't work just because of the order?

Comment: It was not the order.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IList SumValues(int value, int times) // you need to define the type for the return list
{
    List<object> sums = new List<object>(); // you could probably use List<int> here instead of object, unless there's some logic outside of this function that treats them as objects
    int incrementedValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) // i++ is the same as i = i+1, but a little cleaner
    {
        sums.Add(incrementedValue);
        incrementedValue += value;
    }

    return sums;
}
```

This will always include '0' in the list

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure, but try using
sums.Add(value * i); instead of your sums.Add(value);

Tip: in your for cycle use i++ instead of i = i + 1. It is more common and also faster to type.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the value of `value` so it will always be the original. `Add` appends the item to the end of the list.